# Disable sorting datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable

**I am trying to disable sorting 'Empty' column.**

I'm adding `bSortable: false, targets: [0], orderable: false`, but no luck.

```
$("#example").DataTable({
  aaSorting: [],
  bPaginate: true,
  aaData: _vIntArrData,
  aoColumns: [{
    sTitle: ""
  }, {
    sTitle: "Category"
  }, {
    sTitle: "Name"
  }, {
    sTitle: "Audience / Coverage"
  }],
  columnDefs: [{
    bSortable: false,
    targets: [0],
    orderable: false
  }]
});
```

What is wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your code like below:

```
$("#example").DataTable({
      "aaSorting": [],
      "bPaginate": true,
      aaData: _vIntArrData,
      columns: [{
        'sTitle': ''
      }, {
        'sTitle': 'Category'
      }, {
        'sTitle': 'Name'
      }, {
        'sTitle': 'Audience / Coverage'
      }],
     "columnDefs": [{ 
         'bSortable': false,
         'aTargets': [0],
         'orderable': false 
     }],

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding `bSortable` to `aoColumns`

```
aoColumns: [{
    sTitle: "",
   "bSortable": false
  }
```